# __new__ not calling __init__ when correct class

Tags: python, pickle

I have a class `Vertex()`

With the following methods:

```
def __new__(cls, pos_x, pos_y, size_x, size_y, text):
        instance = super(Vertex, cls).__new__(cls)
        #print 'variables {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}'.format(pos_x, pos_y, size_x, size_y, text)
        #print instance.__class__.__name__

        return instance

def __init__(self, pos_x=None, pos_y=None, size_x=None, size_y=None, text=None):
        print 'init'
        super(Vertex, self).__init__()
```

In the method of another class I have the call:

```
self.vertices[touch.uid] = Vertex(pos_x=self.bounds[3][0], pos_y=self.bounds[2][1], size_x=self.bounds[1][0] - self.bounds[3][0], size_y= self.bounds[0][1] - self.bounds[2][1], text=None)
```

which behaves as expected, and creates the `Vertex()` by calling both `__new__()` and `__init__()`

However, when I unpickle a `Vertex()` the `__new__()` method is called but not the `__init__()` method. I checked, and on unpickling the class of the instance is `Vertex`, so as far as I know `__init__()` should be called.

Comment: No, unpickling **deliberately** does not call `__init__`; you are re-instating the instance, not creating a new one.

Comment: If there is code in `__init__()` that I need to run, what is the best way to resolve this? `__setstate__()`?

Comment: Or rather, a new instance is created, but it is "initialized" with the unpicked object, not its own `__init__` method?

Comment: @chepner: sorta-kinda. It's state is restored.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ultimately, I have some sub-objects that I need to re-create (they don't work with pickle) which is why I need the code in `__init__()`

Comment: Possibly, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9409097/677122) can help you a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpickling deliberately does not call `__init__` when reinstating an object. It creates a new 'empty' object (with `__new__`) then re-applies state to it.

You can [customize this process](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances) by implementing either `__getinitargs__` (to tell Pickle to call `__init__` *anyway*, with given arguments) or to hook into `__setstate__`:

```
def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.__dict__.update(state)
    # do other things that need to be set on unpickling.
```

Comment: I tried using `__getinitargs__()` without any success. As I was using `pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL ` my understanding that this would not be called. Very confusing to say the least... I ended up using a combination of `__getstate__()` / `__setstate__()` and dropped `__new__()` and `__getnewargs__()`. I called `self.__init__()` within `__setstate__()` to get the desired effect.